# What's removing my injected element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to prototype a UI with jquery which allows a pair of li elements to be added at the end of a list. The first pair goes well, but as additional pairs are added, one of the two earlier injected elements (li.box) disappears. Only one li.box will ever remain on the page. I cannot figure out why.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="ruleset" class="ruleset">
    <li class="rule"">
        <div class="text">Rule </div>
        <select name="join" class="join">
            <option value="+">+</option>
            <option value="AND">AND</option>
            <option value="OR">OR</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var liBox=$('<li>').attr('class','box').text('>');
    $('body').on('change', 'select.join', function(){ 
        var copy=$(this).parent().clone();
        var li = $(this).parent();
        var par=li.parent();
        li.after(liBox); //an item between each rule to eventually contain controls
        par.append(copy); //a copy of the rule item
    });
});
```

Comment: look, it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/XxX9Q/

Comment: You're only creating one element on page load, and then moving that around, so it's not strange at all?

Comment: `li.after(liBox.clone());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery will not actually clone the li.box but rather just move it. so your code should read :

```
li.after(liBox.clone());
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yqXhM/1/

Comment: Interesting! Could you add a resource or link to a explanation/documentation?